# MySql strange performance

Tags: mysql, performance

First of all, for example I have 3 table A, B, C. Table A has relation with table B and table has relation with table C. I want to get SUM of some field from table A which depends on some fields from table C.

Table A has > 300k rows, Table B has > 4k rows, Table C has ~ 100 rows

My query looks like that:

```
SELECT SUM(a.hours) AS total 
FROM table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b 
  ON a.table_b_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN table_c c
  ON b.table_c_id = c.id 
WHERE a.customer_id = 1
  AND c.title IN ('Title D','Title E')
```

Query execution time is ~7 sec, it's very slow. But execution time of query like below is ~0.0 sec.

```
SELECT a.hours
FROM table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b
  ON a.table_b_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN table_c c
  ON b.table_c_id = c.id
WHERE a.customer_id = 1
  AND c.title IN ('Title D','Title E')
```

Why SUM is so slow? what should I do?

Comment: Do you have an index on Title in Table C?

Comment: Your first query is actually the same as using INNER JOINs and MySQL is quite stupid in optimizing useless Outer Joins. And the 2nd query might be the same as no join at all if there are proper PK-FK relations (and maybe the MySQL can eliminate unneeded joins, but I don't think so)

Comment: Why is this tagged with mongodb and postgresql?

Comment: the title is causing a table scan

Comment: Drew Pierce i also tried "AND c.title IN ('Title D','Title E')" changed to "AND c.id IN (1,2)" it's same time.

Comment: Run the 0.0 sec query as `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`; you may be in for a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Move your condition to `ON` clause for related table:

```
SELECT SUM(a.hours) AS total 
FROM table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b 
  ON a.table_b_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN table_c c
  ON b.table_c_id = c.id 
  AND c.title IN ('Title D','Title E')
WHERE a.customer_id = 1
```

**EDIT 1** According to @dnoeth comment I can agree, probably we should use `inner join` when join `table_c`:

```
SELECT SUM(a.hours) AS total 
FROM table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b 
  ON a.table_b_id = b.id 
INNER JOIN table_c c
  ON b.table_c_id = c.id 
  AND c.title IN ('Title D','Title E')
WHERE a.customer_id = 1
```

Comment: Ok, now its about ~1 sec. Like it.

Comment: @user3234484: It's fast, but it's not the same result as your 1st query :-)

Comment: oops... maybe you are right... we should use `inner join` when joining `table_c`

Comment: The title clause can go either place (`ON` vs `WHERE`) for an `INNER JOIN`.  But it matters for a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` in both places and add this composite index:

```
INDEX(customer_id, title)
```